# How to get object color using JAVA TOOLBOX IFC2x3/IFC4?

Tags: java, parsing, toolbox, ifc

Here I have ifcColumn as IfcProduct for example

```
for (IfcProduct product : products) {
        product <==

from ifc file there are colors defined as 

#11979= IFCCOLOURRGB('Light Gray',0.6,0.6,0.6);
```

So anyone knows how to get color of this product. I have tried open that ifc file in ifcviewer and every object has some color. so please anyone knows?